# Regex, split at groups and get numbers

Tags: regex

https://regexr.com/5u8j6

Expression: `(?<=\/)(\d*)`

```
/v1/vehicles/A123
/v1/vehicles/123
/v1/vehicles/123/456
/v1/vehicles/999fd7d6-1b79-4471-9954-3d63deabaa31
```

Must match with:

```
123
123,456
```

But I am getting `999` too

Comment: You can use a word boundary `(?<=\/)\d+\b` and you can omit the capture group https://regex101.com/r/RVw6HG/1

Comment: wow, this was so fast... thank you @Thefourthbird works greatly

Comment: Note that this would then still match "999" when your value would be something like `/v1/vehicles/999-1b79-4471-9954-3d63deabaa31`. You could solve that using `\/(\d+)(?=$|\/)` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents to solving your problem:

```
\/(\d+)(?=$|\/)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/COT5wv/1)

- `\/` - A literal forward slahs.
- `(\d+)` - A capture group to match 1+ digits ranging 0-9.
- `(?=$|\/)` - Positive lookahead to match end-string anchor **or** a literal forward slash.

---

Other options could be:

```
(?<=\/)\d+(?=$|\/)
```

Or:

```
\/\K\d+(?=$|\/)
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks. I just don't think it's exactly what OP is looking for since I have a feeling the data can actually be something like: `/v1/vehicles/999-1b79` and yield unwanted results. But, if OP is confirms that won't be the case your answer is cleaner =)

Comment: `(?<=\/)\d+(?=$|\/)` works for all cases commented

Answer (score 2):

This will help, too:

```js
(?<=\/)([0-9]+)(?![^\/])
```

See [this proof](https://regex101.com/r/QavQ99/1) (only test one string by one).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\/]                    any character except: '\/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```